# Require a specific item in an array

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following `json` object:

```
{
  "my_items": [
    { "a": "primary", n: 1 },
    { "b": "secondary", n: 2 },
    { "b": "secondary", n: 3 }
  ]
}
```

All items in the `my_items` list are expected to be unique. Now, I need to validate the entire `json` object with the following rule:

> it may contain zero or multiple items with `"type": "secondary"`, but it absolutely **must** contain one and only one item with `"type": "primary"`.

How can this be expressed using latest [`json-schema`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wright-json-schema-validation-01)?

I'm come up with the [following](https://runkit.com/embed/ymkf881z85av):

```
var schema = {
  "definitions": {
    "primary_item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "type":"string",
          "enum":["primary"]
        }
      }
    },
    "secondary_item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "b": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum":["secondary"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "my_items": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "contains": {"$ref": "#/definitions/primary_item"},
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {"$ref": "#/definitions/primary_item"},
          {"$ref": "#/definitions/secondary_item"}
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
};

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

test({
  "my_items": [
    {"a": "primary"},
    {"b": "secondary"},
    {"b": "secondary"}
  ]
});
```

But the tests are failing, with the following errors:

```
Invalid: data.my_items[0] should NOT have additional properties, data.my_items[1] should NOT have additional properties, data.my_items[2] should NOT have additional properties
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in JSON Schema to assert that an array contains one and only one of something.  You can assert there is at least one, but that's the best you can do.  The closest you can get is to require that the primary_item is the first element in the array.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "my_items": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/primary_item"}
      ],
      "additionalItems": {"$ref": "#/definitions/secondary_item"}
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "primary_item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "enum":["primary"] }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "secondary_item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "b": { "enum":["secondary"] }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Responding to the comment

> I wonder if **one and only one** could be expressed using two concepts: `at least one` + `unique`.

Yes.  If your array items are unique you can do the following.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "my_items": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/my_item" },
      "allOf": [{"$ref": "#/definitions/contains_primary_item"}],
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "my_item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "primary_item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "enum":["primary"] }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "contains_primary_item": {
      "not": {
        "items": {
          "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/primary_item" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if **one and only one** could be expressed using two concepts: `at least one` + `unique`. What do you think?

I figured in reality all objects in the list will always be unique (while my examples implies I may have duplicates, which is not true; I have updated the question).